# Statusbar not getting transparent instead getting milky color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have implemented the following code for getting the transparent status bar but not able to
Kindly help me.
If fitSystemWindows is true then status bar not getting transparent and if fitSystemWindows is false to rootlayout then content is going below navigation bar.
I have applied following code before setting content view on my activty.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void setFullTheme(Activity activity){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

This is the theme I have applied to the activity

```
<style name="ThemeFullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

By implementing these the status bar got transparent but navigation bar too got transluscent and hence the content was going behind the navigation bar.
So I applied android:fitSystemWindows="true" to the root view but after that status bar got milky color.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_container_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frag_home"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_member_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Following picture,when I set true to fitSystemWindows in root layout. Content goes behind navigation bar.
[image]

Following picture,when I remove the fitSystemWindows property in root layout. Status bar color goes white.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

put `android:fitSystemWindows="true"`  again and change `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` attribute in your theme as `false`

nevigate to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr documentation and you can find out

> The window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with
>   windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds and the navigation bar must not have
>   been requested to be translucent with windowTranslucentNavigation.
>   Corresponds to Window.setNavigationBarColor(int).

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But it didn't worked out .

Comment: Is that same issue yoiu got ?

Comment: Yes. Getting the status bar color as white as shown in the image above.